# Is there a redmine plugin to create multiple issues at once?

Tags: redmine, issue-tracking, redmine-plugins

Redmine has a nice batch edit feature, but nothing equivalent for "batch create" (please correct me if I'm wrong!)

FogBugz lets you quickly create multiple tickets with the same properties (type, status, assignment, etc.) via a ajax-ified text box at the bottom of any filtered view of tickets. Tickets created this way match the values of the filter (and the filter grouping value - there's a text-box at the bottom of each group).

Toodledo has simpler option: it's "Add multiple tasks" feature is a textarea where each line is turned into an item.

Is there a redmine plugin out there that adds functionality like either of the above?

Comment: Could this be done with an import plugin?

Comment: Anything changed meanwhile? 6 years have passed since the question was asked.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't seen such plugin, but for me the *duplicate* function cover the need (typically create the same bug report for different releases of the project, says trunk and branches where fix will be backported).

Answer (score 1):

You could tryout the MS Project 2007 Import/Export plugin
http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/16705